# Reject inference

Tags: credit-scoring, reject-inference

What are the most effective techniques for reject inference in the context of retail credit scoring.  [Parcelling](http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2008/ST-160.pdf) is something I use frequently... Any other approaches out there?

Comment: Nice question; well done!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [bivariate probit model](http://www.defaultrisk.eu/img_auth.php/a/a3/%7E2660380.pdf) at all?

> Bivariate probit model with sample
> selection assumes that the
> distribution of the accepted applicant
> population is different from that of
> the rejected applicant population.
> That is, it is assumed that
>
> $P(default|X, rejected) \neq P(default|X, accepted)$
>
> for some vector of
> explanatory variables X of the model
> predicting the default of companies.

I addition to that paper, there's an article that highlights different approaches available here: [Theoretical approaches of reject inference](http://www.defaultrisk.eu/img_auth.php/2/26/Theoretical_approaches_of_reject_inference.pdf).

It gives overviews of:

- Several different parceling methods
- Fuzzy reclassification
- Iterative reclassification
- Three-groups approach

among others.